# Pulling specific terms from a string-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, charindex

I am having a column of Full name like:

```
Fullname
-----------------------
Joel (MD),Garris
Yong (MD),Park
Kristen (DO),Kenny
Jr, Jack (MD),Freimann
FirstName (title), LastName
```

What I actually want is FirstName only. I have tried following but cant get the result.

I tried using CHARINDEX and SUBSTRING but still dint find any result:

```
Replace(SUBSTRING(@aa,1,(CHARINDEX('(',@aa))),',','')
```

Tried to pull title seperately and then tried to replace it by null:

```
Replace(FullName,SUBSTRING(Fullname, CHARINDEX('(',Fullname,0),CHARINDEX(')',Fullname,CHARINDEX('(',Fullname,0))),'')
```

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another sample that parse with PARSNAME

```
declare @tb table (Fullname varchar(400))    
    Insert into @tb values ('Joel (MD),Garris')
    Insert into @tb values ('Yong (MD),Park')
    Insert into @tb values ('Kristen (DO),Kenny')
    Insert into @tb values ('Jr, Jack (MD),Freimann')
    Insert into @tb values ('FirstName (title), LastName')

select PARSENAME(REPLACE(Fullname,'(','.'),2) from @tb
```

```
Joel 
Yong 
Kristen 
Jr, Jack 
FirstName
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you need the `replace`, but here is a use of `substring` that will get you only the first name:

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T As TABLE
(
    Fullname varchar(30)
)

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('Joel (MD),Garris'),
('Yong (MD),Park'),
('Kristen (DO),Kenny'),
('Jr, Jack (MD),Freimann'),
('FirstName (title), LastName')
```

The query: (note the use of case to avoid errors if there is no `(` in the string)

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('(', FullName) > 1 THEN
           SUBSTRING(FullName, 1, CHARINDEX('(', FullName) - 1)
       ELSE
           FullName
       END As FirstName
FROM @T
```

Results:

```
FirstName
Joel 
Yong 
Kristen 
Jr, Jack 
FirstName
```

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting string from '('

```
   declare @name table (Fullname varchar(400))    
    Insert into @name values ('Joel (MD),Garris')
    Insert into @name values ('Yong (MD),Park')
    Insert into @name values ('Kristen (DO),Kenny')
    Insert into @name values ('Jr, Jack (MD),Freimann')
    Insert into @name values ('FirstName (title), LastName')

select substring (fullname,0,charindex('(',fullname)) from @name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Fullname, 1, CASE CHARINDEX('(', Fullname)
   WHEN 0
      THEN LEN(Fullname)
   ELSE CHARINDEX('/', Fullname) - 1
   END) AS FirstName 
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you are having following table structure;

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (Fullname VARCHAR(50))
```

and

```
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('Joel (MD),Garris')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('Yong (MD),Park')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('Kristen (DO),Kenny')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('Jr, Jack (MD),Freimann')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('FirstName (title), LastName ')
INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('aaa, bbb')
```

Get FirstName only from table as:

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN charindex('(', Fullname, 1) = 0
            THEN Fullname
        ELSE LEFT(Fullname, charindex('(', Fullname, 1) - 2)
        END AS FirstNameOnly
FROM #temp
```

I have used **charindex** to get index of '(' and then I have used **LEFT** function to get characters of Fullname starting from left to that character index, i have deducted additional one index to get rid of space after firstname.

I have used **case when then**, in case you don't have stored '(' in your column.
You can remove that **case when then**, if you are sure that, you'll always have '(' stored in your column as:

```
SELECT LEFT(Fullname, charindex('(', Fullname, 1) - 2) AS FirstNameOnly
FROM #temp
```